# Search in Manage Groups renders "contacts" link as editable under "visibility column"

Tags: groups, theme

CiviCRM 4.7.17. It should be noted that we upgraded from the latest LTS about 2 weeks ago. On Drupal 7.x

Is this a Civi bug, or a theme bug?

1. Before we search for a group.

[image: Before we search for a group]

2. After we search for a group

[image: After we search for a group]

3. When we click 'Contacts' we see Group Visibility as editable choice

[image: When we click 'contacts' we see this]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The screenshots also show you have names in the 'Count' column and a 'mailchimp sync' column which is not standard.  If you disable the mailchimp extension, or whatever else is changing that results display, do you get the same issues?

Comment: Correct! I found the bug on their issue queue too; https://github.com/veda-consulting/uk.co.vedaconsulting.mailchimp/issues/262